# Hosting Rails on local network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I have been deploying my rails app to digitalocean on ubuntu OS and it's working fine. However, I would like to deploy my rails app on a local ubuntu network.

I have tried to setup rails on ubuntu and it's working fine and I am able to open network access with port 3000 by the same network to access via

```
$ rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

This a bit slow from another local network computer to access. What is the better way where I can deploy rails app to my local server and only for same local network usage.

Comment: change envrionment to production - that makes your application a bit faster. then optimize your application as much as you can - do caching, avoid n+1 queries if there are any etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been doing the same thing on a Raspberry pi with several projects.

You can actually treat your local server like an external one. You can deploy on the local server using capistrano.

Just make sure that your app on your local server will be deployed as production, not development. I would also recommend NGINX and unicorn for performance and zero downtime deployment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't have knowledge on Rasphberry pi, may I know can Raspberry pi setup for VPN access so that I can access it via VPN?

Comment: Glad I could help! Yes you can! This is exactly what I am doing! You can also have encryption while on public wifi using this VPN. You can find more info on this here. https://sys.jonaharagon.com/2016/05/12/setting-up-an-openvpn-server-on-a-raspberry-pi-2-part-12/

Comment: Thanks Jeremie. that is helpful. My friend told me Rasphberry pi may not be solid for long run usage due to it may spoil easily. Or does it only apply for the first version of Rasphberry pi? Do you have any suggestion?